# Rails 3 no routes matches (nested resources?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have a one to many association in rails where a user has_many :albums and albums belongs_to :user. Everything works fine but the index page. Whenever I try going to the index page I get the No routes matches error. Is there something I am doing wrong? All of my pages work except the index page which shows all the albums.

**Here's the error(Array with all information, I truncated most of it)*

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"albums", :user_id=>[#<User id: 3}
```

**Routes.rb**

```
  resources :users do
    resources :albums
  end
```

**albums_controller.rb**

```
class AlbumsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @albums = Album.all
    @user = User.all
  end

  def show
    @album = Album.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @album = Album.new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def edit
    @album = Album.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @album = current_user.albums.create(params[:album])

     if @album.save
       redirect_to user_albums_path, :notice => 'Album was successfully created.' 
     else
       render :action => "new"
     end
  end

  def update
    @album = Album.find(params[:id])

      if @album.update_attributes(params[:album])
        redirect_to user_album_path(@album), :notice => 'Album was successfully updated.' 
      else
      render :action => "new"
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @album = Album.find(params[:id])
    @album.destroy
  end
end
```

**The form for albums**

```
<%= form_for ([:user, @album]) , :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
```

**Albums index.html.erb**

```
<% for albums in @albums %>
 <tr>
   <td><%= albums.title %></td>
   <td><%= albums.description %></td>
   <td><%= albums.user_id %></td>
   <td><%= link_to 'Show', user_album_path(@user, albums) %></td>
   <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_album_path(@user, albums) %></td>
   <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', user_album_path(@user, albums), confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete %></td>
</tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: It'd be helpful to have your `routes.rb` file as well.

Comment: Forgot about that routes.rb is now added.

Comment: So you're trying to access `example.com/users/albums/` ? That should be hitting the index action, not the show (which the error indicates). Are you using a link or typing it in manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and I figured it all out I was not calling the user before specifying the albums which in most cases were `@user = User.find(params[:user_id])`